# HTML5 image transformation library, no flash

Tags: html

I found http://www.magmypic.com/, the concept is super nice, but flash is SO OUT... i like and think if it's possible to do it in html5. Do you know library that can do it, or site that show how-to

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need 'HTML5' so do something similar, the first step is placing an image as a background of a div and using CSS3 'background-position' and 'background-size' take care of moving and scaling the image. Then just slap transparent PNG on top for the magazine text. You could also use CSS3 instead of a PNG to make the magazine graphics with @font-face and something like [google web fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) or [font squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) for custom fonts.